# How to use ScipyOptimizerInterface in tf.learn.LinearClassifier?

Tags: tensorflow, scipy, scipy-optimize

I want to try some second order optimization in tf.learn, but I couldn't figure out how. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post some code what you have right now

Answer (score 0):

With older TensorFlow (dating it to your question):

```python
import tensorflow as tf
vector = tf.Variable([7., 7.], 'vector')
# Make vector norm as small as possible.
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vector))

optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(
    loss, options={'maxiter': 100})

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(session.run(vector))  # results: [7.0, 7.0]
    optimizer.minimize(session)
    print(session.run(vector))  # results: [ -1.88996808e-06  -1.88996808e-06]
```